# Why do we make "window.x = x = ..." in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, webrtc

In WebRTC official sample I have found in few places the following code:

```
var pc1;
...//some code
function call() {
  //...some code
  // Add pc1 to global scope so it's accessible from the browser console
  window.pc1 = pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  //...
}
```

On W3C Tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) I've found, that:

```
var carName = "Volvo";

// code here can use window.carName
```

Because in HTML, window object is a global scope.

So there is my question- is there any logic, that they used

```
window.pc1 = pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

instead of simple

```
pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

I'm not a javascript developer, so that's a little bit confusing to find such statement in official WebRTC tutorial when yesterday I've just read that such statement is illogical.

Comment: There is no need for that, since inside the `call` function's score the `pc1` variable is global (which means - its the same as `window.pc1`.

Comment: Had they used `let pc1;` then it would have made a difference.

Comment: @jib no let, no var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code snippet as you post it no there is no reason this is done as pc1 will be accessible in the global scope anyway.

It is however, due to the exact same scoping nature of javascript for developers to wrap code in [iffe's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to avoid polluting the global scope with all these variables.

If the code snippet was wrapped in an iffe then it would make a difference to declare as in that statement because otherwise (and as the comment above suggests) the variable would not be accessible on the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Difference is if you have a local variable of same name, then using `pc1` inside function will return different value compared to using it outside;

```js
window.x = 10;

function notify(){
  var x = 20;
  console.log(x)
}
console.log(x)

notify()
```

Ideally, you should only use `window.pc1` as you have a global copy. But there can be a case where you wish to have a different value and based on it you wish to update both. Under such circumstances, you can use

```
window.pc1 = pc1 = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code — and I agree it looks a bit odd :).

In fact, I think it was just a mistake. The intention was to make `pc1` visible from the console — but this is unnecessary, since the `var pc1;` declaration already does this. (Maybe `window.` was necessary at some point, to to make a variable visible in the console? Can't remember.)

Hope that makes sense.

Been a while since I worked on this, but the code here is different: [github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js)